# addItem only to Magento cms_page via local.xml can't use theme?

Tags: magento

Magento doesn't want to look in my theme folder for these JS files when I use this code in local.xml

```
<!-- /app/design/frontend/my-theme/default/layout/local.xml -->
<xml>
  <cms_page>
    <reference name="head">
      <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>my.js</name><params/></action>
    </reference>
   </cms_page>
</xml>
```

This results in

```
<head>
    <script src="http://example.com/skin/frontend/base/default/my.js" />
</head>
```

whereas if I where to put the same XML code within the "default" xml tag it loads correctly. i.e....

```
<!-- /app/design/frontend/my-theme/default/layout/local.xml -->
<xml>
  <default>
    <reference name="head">
      <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>my.js</name><params/></action>
    </reference>
  </default>
</xml>
```

loads...

```
<head>
    <script src="http://example.com/skin/frontend/MYTHEME/default/my.js" />
</head>

    <!-- Emphasis Added -->
```

The problem is that I only want to load this script for cms_pages. Is this impossible?

Using Magento 1.6 ~ The and yes, I've cleared the cache ;)

Oh, and my design configuration ( admin > configuration > design ) has "package" set to "my-theme", and the "default" set to "default"

Answer (score 0):

The reason it ends up using the wrong URL when loading CMS pages is likely that you have a custom theme set on that CMS page.

The custom theme you define on a per-page level overrides the normal theme when the CMS page is rendered.

Check your CMS page settings under the custom design section.

Comment: Hi Lee, 'preciate the help, but I think my question wasn't clear enough. The problem is not with the page URL, but rather the script src. You see, I only want to load this script for CMS pages (i.e. about, 404, home). Magento requires that you set a template for any CMS pages created in the backend. 

The above code works in that it tries to load the javascript when on a cms_page. The problem is that it's not looking in the theme's skin folder. Could this be a bug? I don't really know how to debug something as big as Magento.

Comment: Well, when you add the addItem call to the 'default' handle and you load a CMS page, are you saying it is correct vs. adding it to the 'cms_page' handle and loading the EXACT same page?